# Cube root of n is irrational or natural

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

I am trying to show that $\sqrt[3] n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is either natural or irrational. I start off by assuming the thesis, that is $\sqrt[3] n = {p \over q} \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ where $q$ doesn't divide $p$ without a remainder. I rewrite $n = {p^3 \over q^3}$ and conclude that for this to be a natural number, $q$ has to divide $p$ without a remainder, so ${p \over q} \in \mathbb{N}$ which contradicts the assumption.

My question is, how exactly do we know that ${p^3 \over q^3} \in \mathbb{N}$ implies ${p \over q} \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Have you seen a proof that $\sqrt n$ is natural or irrational? You should be able to modify it to work for cubes (and 4th powers, and fifth powers, and....).

Comment: The one I saw looks almost exactly like what I wrote above, only with second powers. Generally, I get that $nq^3=p^3$ so $q^3$ divides $p^3$. The part that is problematic, as indicated above, is why this implies $q|p$. I sort of "see" it in an informal way.

Comment: Right. So, how did they get around that, in the proof you saw?

Comment: This is the reasoning I analyzed: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/4400irrationals.pdf It relies on the fact that the square of an odd number is always odd.

Comment: OK. Well, the cube of an odd number is always odd, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formal answer of your question could be as follows,$(p,q)=1$:

$${p^3 \over q^3}=a, (a \in \mathbb{N})→{p^3 \over q}=aq^2→p^2({p \over q})=aq^2→{p \over q} \in \mathbb{N}$$

This because (in general) if $a({m \over n})=b$ and $(a,n)=1$, then ${m \over n} \in \mathbb{N}$.

(For more detail about the later statement, please see: [Suppose $a,b,m,n$ are natural numbers, prove that if $a({m \over n})=b$ and $(a,n)=1$, then ${m \over n} \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984311/suppose-a-b-m-n-are-natural-numbers-prove-that-if-am-over-n-b-and-a))

Answer (score 1):

If $p/q$ is a root of $x^3 - n = 0$, where $p,q$ have no common divisors other than $\pm 1$ then $q$ divides 1 (the leading coefficient) and hence $p/q \in \mathbb{N}$.