# Cube root of $4$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I would like to see if this proof is correct. I will really appreciate it.

> Suppose that ${4}^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is rational. Then there exists $a,b
>  \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ with $\frac{a}{b} =
>  4^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
>
> Then $a^3 = 4b^3$. (So from here I want to show that $a,b$ are in fact
>   not coprime).
>
> Since from assumption, $a,b$ are coprime, then $a^3 | 4$. This implies
>   $a$ is even (I think?!).
>
> So $a = 2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Hence, $4b^3 = 8k^3 \implies b^3 \stackrel{(\star)}{=} 2k^3.$ Since $b
> > \nmid a$ then $b\nmid 2k$ so $b \nmid 2$ and $b\nmid k$ by Euclid's
>   Lemma.   But if this is true, then $b^3 \nmid 2$ and $b^3 \nmid k^3$.
>   So $b^3 \neq 2k^3$ which contradicts $(\star)$.

This feels weird, because I feel like I should contradict one of my hypotheses, not something I found along the way...

Comment: You hypothesized that a,b are coprime and then contradicted that. Without that hypothesis you would not have been able to get that a is even.

Comment: Don't you mean $4\mid a^3$?

Comment: When doing a proof by contradiction, any contradiction you can reach is fine. If you want to be pedantic about it, since $a, b$ being coprime implies $(\star)$, we see that the negation of $(\star)$ implies the negation of $a$ and $b$ being coprime, by contrapositivity. So you're golden on that account. Often, proofs by contradiction contradict completely different, seemingly unrelated things, like $3$ being an even number.

Comment: @Shaun I did mean $a^3 | 4$ because I thought if $a^3 = 4b^3$, then since $a\nmid b$ then $a$ must divide $4$.

Comment: I see. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Natash1 But then from $a\mid 4$ you can conclude $a\in\{1,2,4\}$ and the rest is easy (though $a$ may be odd).

Comment: Wait: I don't see how you deduced $b^3\neq 2k^3$.

Comment: @Natash1 ;See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984065/cube-root-of-n-is-irrational-or-natural

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for that. Indeed, I thought if $x\nmid y$ and $x\nmid z$ then $x\nmid yz$.

Comment: Once we get to $4^{1/3}$, I think my strategy would be to prove _in general_ that the $n$th root of a natural number is always either natural or irrational, for every $n$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if $k|mn$ that either $k|m$ completely or $k|n$ completely. Which isn't true if k is not prime.  $a^3|4b^3$ can implie $a|4$ which can inductively conclude $a^3|4$.  That doesn't mean $a$ is even as $a$ could be $1$. $b^3\not\mid 2k^3$ does not mean $b^3\not \mid 2$ nor does it mean $b^3\not \mid k^3$.  But $b$ and $k$ being relatively prime *would* mean $b^3|2$ which would imply $b = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`proof-verification`:

> Suppose that ${4}^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is rational. Then there exists $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ with $\frac{a}{b} = 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$.
>
> Then $a^3 = 4b^3$. (So from here I want to show that $a,b$ are in fact not coprime `(so that I would have a contradiction)`).
>
> Since from `the` assumption, $a,b$ are coprime, then $a^3 | 4$. `(Why? Maybe you want to conclude that` $4|a^3$`?)` This implies $a$ is even (I think?!). `(Why? This step is unclear.)`
>
> So $a = 2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. `(Assuming you have shown` $a$ `is even, I keep reading.)`
>
> Hence, $4b^3 = 8k^3 \implies b^3 \stackrel{(\star)}{=} 2k^3.$ Since $b \nmid a$ <s>then</s>`, i.e.` $b\nmid 2k$`,` so $b \nmid 2$ and $b\nmid k$ by Euclid's Lemma. `(Euclid's lemma says: "If a prime p divides the product ab of two integers a and b, p must divide at least one of those integers a and b." I don't see how it is used here. It seems that you use it in a wrong way. Your argument breaks down and I would stop reading from here.)`

Answer (score 4):

In your proof $a$ might be $1$.

If $a=1$ then $b$ must be a prositive integer because $\sqrt[3]{4}$ is a positive number,i.e $b \in \mathbb{N}$

So you can say that if $a=1$ then from the fact that $b \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $1=b \sqrt[3]{4}>1$ which is a contradiction.

Now you can prove your statement in this simpler way if you want:

> $2$ is a prime number therefore if $2|a^k$ for some positive integer $k>1$ then $2|a$
>
> We have that $4|a^3$ thus $2|a^3 \Rightarrow 2|a \Rightarrow a=2k$
>
> From this we see that  $$4b^3=8k^3 \Rightarrow b^3=4k^3 \Rightarrow 2|b^3 \Rightarrow 2|b$$
>
> Thus we have : $$2|a$$ $$2|b$$
>
> So from this we contradict our assumption about $(a,b)=1$
>
> and the proof is finished.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear how $a^3\mid 4$, how $a$ is even, nor how $b^3\neq 2k^3$; besides: $a^3\mid 4$ could imply $a^3=1$ *a priori* - you'd have to argue that $a\neq 1$ by approximating $4^\frac13$.

Since $a^3=4b^3$, we have $4\mid a^3$, which implies that $a$ is even as $2$ is prime.

If you deduce *any* contradiction from the hypothesis that $4^{\frac13}$ is rational, it means that it is indeed irrational. There's nothing weird about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it stronger and quicker.

But first we need to be clear:

Lemma:  If $a$ and $b$ are coprime then $a|kb \implies a|k$.

Lemma 2: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime then $a^m|kb^n \implies a^m|k$.

These lemmas are acceptable if we assume every number has a  prime factorization.

So $a^3 = 4b^3$ would imply $a^3|4$.

But that is a *REALLY* strong statement!

$a^3 = 4b^3 \implies 1 = \frac {4}{a^3}b^3$ but $1$ is unitary so $\frac 4{a^3} =1$ and $a^3 = 4$.  So the cube root of $4$ must be an integer if it is rational!

Well.  $a \le 0\implies a^3 \le 0 < 4$.  And $1^3 = 1 \ne 4$.  And if $a \ge 2$ then $a^3 \ge 2*a^2 \ge 2*2*a \ge 2*2*2 = 8 > 4$.

.... or ... if we can assume that every integer has a *unique* prime factorization.  (Cany you in your class and these stage?) then $a^3 = \prod p_i^{3a_i} = 2^2$ is .... impossible.